# How to validate time in python

Tags: python

I'm creating a simple time keeping, but I have a hard time with my logic, `if the user log between 10:00 AM to 10:15 AM or 12:00 PM or 3:00 PM to 3:15 PM` the status will be `BREAK OUT` which it works, and when the user log `05:00PM to 11:00PM` the status will be `TIME OUT` but when the user log between `5:00AM to 4:00PM` the status is still in `TIME OUT` that suppose to be a `TIME IN`.

Here is my code:

```
def set_time(fk):
                status = 'TIME IN'

                print('RESULT: ' + datetime.strptime(self.request.POST['time'], '%I:%M:%S %p').strftime('%I:%M %p'))
                print('set')

                user_time = datetime.strptime(self.request.POST['time'], '%I:%M:%S %p').strftime('%I:%M %p')

                if (user_time >= datetime.strptime('10:00 AM', '%I:%M %p').strftime('%I:%M %p') \
                and user_time <= datetime.strptime('10:15 AM', '%I:%M %p').strftime('%I:%M %p')) \
                or user_time >= datetime.strptime('12:00 PM', '%I:%M %p').strftime('%I:%M %p') \
                or (user_time >= datetime.strptime('03:00 PM', '%I:%M %p').strftime('%I:%M %p') \
                and user_time <= datetime.strptime('03:15 PM', '%I:%M %p').strftime('%I:%M %p')):
                    TimeLogsModel.objects.create(date = fk,
                    time = self.request.POST['time'],
                    status = 'BREAK OUT')
                    status = 'BREAK OUT'

                elif user_time >= datetime.strptime('05:00 AM', '%I:%M %p').strftime('%I:%M %p') \
                and user_time <= datetime.strptime('04:00 PM', '%I:%M %p').strftime('%I:%M %p'):
                    TimeLogsModel.objects.create(date = fk,
                    time = self.request.POST['time'],
                    status = 'TIME IN')
                    status = 'TIME IN'

                elif user_time >= datetime.strptime('05:00 PM', '%I:%M %p').strftime('%I:%M %p') \
                and user_time <= datetime.strptime('11:00 PM', '%I:%M %p').strftime('%I:%M %p'):
                    TimeLogsModel.objects.create(date = fk,
                    time = self.request.POST['time'],
                    status = 'TIME OUT')
                    status = 'TIME OUT'
                
                return status
```

I updated in to this:

```
def set_time(fk):
                status = 'TIME IN'

                datemask = '%I:%M %p'
                
                print('RESULT: ' + datetime.strptime(self.request.POST['time'], '%I:%M:%S %p').strftime(datemask))
                print('set')

                user_time = datetime.now().strftime(datemask)
                print('USER TIME: ' + str(user_time))

                if (user_time >= datetime.strptime('10:00 AM', datemask).strftime(datemask) \
                and user_time <= datetime.strptime('10:15 AM', datemask).strftime(datemask)):
                    TimeLogsModel.objects.create(date = fk,
                    time = self.request.POST['time'],
                    status = 'BREAK OUT')
                    status = 'BREAK OUT'
                
                elif user_time >= datetime.strptime('12:00 PM', datemask).strftime(datemask) and \
                user_time <= datetime.strptime('12:59 PM', datemask).strftime(datemask):
                    TimeLogsModel.objects.create(date = fk,
                    time = self.request.POST['time'],
                    status = 'BREAK OUT')
                    status = 'BREAK OUT'

                elif user_time >= datetime.strptime('03:00 PM', datemask).strftime(datemask) \
                and user_time <= datetime.strptime('03:15 PM', datemask).strftime(datemask):
                    TimeLogsModel.objects.create(date = fk,
                    time = self.request.POST['time'],
                    status = 'BREAK OUT')
                    status = 'BREAK OUT'

                elif user_time >= datetime.strptime('05:00 AM', datemask).strftime(datemask) \
                and user_time <= datetime.strptime('04:00 PM', datemask).strftime(datemask):
                    TimeLogsModel.objects.create(date = fk,
                    time = self.request.POST['time'],
                    status = 'TIME IN')
                    status = 'TIME IN'

                elif user_time >= datetime.strptime('05:00 PM', datemask).strftime(datemask) \
                and user_time <= datetime.strptime('11:00 PM', datemask).strftime(datemask):
                    TimeLogsModel.objects.create(date = fk,
                    time = self.request.POST['time'],
                    status = 'TIME OUT')
                    status = 'TIME OUT'
                
                return status
```

Comment: You shouldn't be doing all of stuff with strings.  Times can be represented directly with `datetime.time` objects.  These objects can be compared just like normal numbers. Only when you want to print a time for a user to see should you convert a time to a string representation. `datetime.time(0, 0)` is midnight, `datetime.time(10, 30)` is 10:30 in the morning.  `datetime.time(12 + 3, 15)` is 3:15 in the afternoon.  These objects are how you should be working with time.

Comment: @Steve I already use time than string but it doesn't work.

Comment: It will work if you do it right.  Your code will be much smaller and easier to read.

Comment: What's the deal with 12:00 PM.  You say "or if the time is 12:00" but then you check for the time to be ">= 12:00 PM" and then check to see if the time is ">= 3:00 PM". Won't the time always be ">= 12:00 PM" if it is ">= 3:00 PM" and so the ">= 3:00 PM" will never happen.  Do you see what I'm asking?  Checking for  "time >= 12:00PM" matches the whole second half of the day.  I don't get how that works. - because of the ">= 12:00 PM" check, it seems that the "5:00PM" to "11:00 PM" thing at the bottom of the code will never happen either.

Comment: @steve see the updated source code, when I try to login @ "1:00 PM" i got a result "TIME IN" which that is what I want and when I try to login between "10:00 AM to 10:15 AM", "12:00 PM to 12:59 PM" , "3:00 to 3:15 PM" i got a result of "BREAK OUT" which I wanted. but when i try to log on the "AM time" it says "TIME OUT".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do yourself (and anyone reading your code, your future self included) a favour by writing functions that have one, clearly defined purpose.

For example:

```
def get_status(self, user_time, start, end, breaks):
    if not (start <= user_time <= end):
        return 'time out'
    else:
        for start_break, end_break in breaks:
            if start_break <= user_time <= end_break:
                return 'break out'
        return 'time in'
```

If I understand your logic correctly, this gives the correct status, given some times, for example:

```
my_object.get_status(time(12, 10), 
                     time(5, 0), time(17, 0), 
                     [(time(10, 0), time(10, 15)), 
                      (time(12, 0), time(13, 00)), 
                      (time(15, 0), time(15, 15))])
```

(line breaks just for clarity)

This would return `'break out'`. You can then use this method from another method that does something with the value that got returned through some web form - separating the code that deals with the form from the code that tests some business rule (i.e. what is the status that goes with some time).

Since it appears you don't really need the start and end times of the work day to be variable, nor the breaks, you probably want to move that to the constructor instead:

```
from datetime import time


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, start, end, breaks):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.breaks = breaks

    def get_status(self, user_time):
        if not (self.start <= user_time <= self.end):
            return 'time out'
        else:
            for start_break, end_break in self.breaks:
                if start_break <= user_time <= end_break:
                    return 'break out'
        return 'time in'


obj = MyClass(time(5, 0), time(17, 0),
              [(time(10, 0), time(10, 15)),
               (time(12, 0), time(13, 00)),
               (time(15, 0), time(15, 15))])

print(obj.get_status(time(12, 10)))
```

Result:

```
break out
```

In your situation probably something like:

```
from datetime import datetime, time


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, start, end, breaks):
        self.start = start
        self.end = end
        self.breaks = breaks

        # you probable have some code that sets this to a valid request
        self.request = None

    def get_status(self, user_time):
        if not (self.start <= user_time <= self.end):
            return 'time out'
        else:
            for start_break, end_break in self.breaks:
                if start_break <= user_time <= end_break:
                    return 'break out'
        return 'time in'

    def set_time(self, fk):
        user_time = datetime.strptime(self.request.POST['time'], '%I:%M:%S %p').time()
        status = self.get_status(user_time)
        # assuming this exists and works
        TimeLogsModel.objects.create(date=fk,
                                     time=self.request.POST['time'],
                                     status=status)
        # just returning the status because you did, not sure you even want that
        return status
```

Comment: Thanks! now it works. and I will understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

It kept eating at me that you were doing all that string manipulation when you shouldn't be.  You should be using time objects directly.  I see that @Grismar has already given you a way to work with times directly.  Still, I spend some time putting something together myself that I'll offer as another example.  It's a bit simpler, I guess, and it has tests to go with it.  Anyway...

```
import datetime

# Define a short alias for "datetime.time"
t = datetime.time

# Our status values
TIME_NONE = "TIME NONE"
BREAK_OUT = "BREAK OUT"
TIME_IN = "TIME IN"
TIME_OUT = "TIME OUT"

# Function that lets us represent AM and PM times in a more readable fashion below
def AM(hours):
    return hours

def PM(hours):
    return hours + 12

# Get the status for the specified time
def get_status(user_time):
    if user_time >= t(AM(10)) and user_time <= t(AM(10), 15) \
            or user_time >= t(PM(3)) and user_time <= t(PM(3), 15) \
            or user_time >= t(AM(12)) and user_time <= t(PM(1), 15):
        status = BREAK_OUT
    elif user_time >= t(AM(5)) and user_time <= t(PM(4)):
        status = TIME_IN
    elif user_time >= t(PM(5)) and user_time <= t(PM(11)):
        status = TIME_OUT
    else:
        status = TIME_NONE
    return status

# Convert a time to a human readable string
def time_to_string(t):
    return t.strftime('%I:%M %p')

# Test that one time meets our expectation in terms of its status
def test(t, expect_status):
    status = get_status(t)
    print(time_to_string(t) + " = " + status + ": ", end = "")
    if status == expect_status:
        print("yes")
    else:
        print("NO!!!!!!!")

def run_tests():
    # Run a test for each time period
    test(t(AM(10), 8), BREAK_OUT)
    test(t(AM(12), 35), BREAK_OUT)
    test(t(PM(3)), BREAK_OUT)
    test(t(AM(6), 30), TIME_IN)
    test(t(PM(9), 45), TIME_OUT)
    test(t(PM(11), 45), TIME_NONE)

run_tests()
```

Comment: Thanks for making some efforts to solve my problem but the first answer worked to my problem.